Can Javers be used to list changes within sub Entities
Let's start with an example of my data:
{
  'id': 'foo',
  'name': 'Me',
  'friends': [
    {
      'id': 'bar',
      'name': 'Mark'
      'location': 'here'
    },
    ...
  ],
  'family': [
    {
      'id': 'baz',
      'name': 'Mom',
      'location': 'there'
    },
    {
      'id': 'bar',
      'name': 'Mark'
      'location': 'here'
    },
    .....
  ],
  acquaintances: []
}

Let's say this is using a basic class such as:
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  String id;
  String name;
  String location;
  List<Person> friends;
  List<Person> family;
  List<Person> acquaintances;
}

In this fictious example I have a root object (id=foo) and two lists of friends and family. The two lists contain the same type (type Person), and they are both @Entity types with their own IDs. Let's say I consider Mark to be adopted family, he's both in friends and family.
Now, if Mark changes his location from 'here' to 'there', I'd like Javers to tell me that it changed in both lists friends and family. Currently though when I use javers.compare(existing, updated);, it seems I would get a set of changes that tells me something like this:
Diff@33 "Diff:
* changes on Person/bar :
  - 'location' changed: 'here' -> 'there'
* changes on Person/bar :
  - 'location' changed: 'here' -> 'there'

What I don't get here is information that Person bar was in both the friends list and the family list on Person/foo. Is it possible to get this information out of a Javers Diff? What I would like to ultimately do is construct a list of changes that looks a little like this:

Pesron/foo.friends[bar].location
Pesron/foo.family[bar].location

